# Communities, Visualforce my profile page

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, profile

When I set up my communities 2 things were added automatically :

- My profile page
- Controller for that profile page

I was playing around with the communities and managed to set everything up including the registration but in the process my profile page just disappeared. It was a page where a customer could go into through a Visualforce based community or a portal and look and change their details for example a user address or email 
 
Does anyone know how to get that page and controller back ? or possibly give me link to the code ? 
 
It was a custom page given by salesforce and I'm 100% sure I didn't delete it by the delete button or on purpose

Comment: Look in your setup history to see what you did.

Comment: Could you point me where the setup history is ?

Comment: Security Controls | Setup Audit Trail

Comment: Thanks never knew this existed it'll definitely be of use one day.  It only says created and changed but nothing about it being deleted.

Comment: Then it must still be there if created and changed. Just need to look a little bit harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My profile page is a home page component, go to the home page layout and see if the component has been unchecked and if the same page layout is assigned to the community user profile.

If no, signup for a free developer edition enable communities and you should be able to see page and the controller there.

Answer (score 0):

It should be added in the Login Settings of your site.  And also make sure your Site Profile has access to the MyProfilePage.

[image]

Comment: updated answer!